# NSView and Swift 3.0

Tags: nsview, drawrect, swift3

I have finally upgraded to Swift 3.0 and encountered a problem - I'm using custom view and its drawrect function to render some drawing, and I override 'isFlipped' var to return true and draw them upside down. Before Swift 3.0 it works like a charm but now Cocoa turns upside down not only this particular drawing but also any other my subviews (which I don't want to have this way). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to return back 'isFlipped' var behavior from Swift 2 so instead I simply rotate coordinates of all my subviews. It could be done like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
   for child in self.view.subviews {
      child.frame = NSRect.init(
                        x: child.frame.minX,
                        y: self.view.frame.height - child.frame.minY - child.frame.height,
                        width: child.frame.width,
                        height: child.frame.height)
    }
}
```